# Best Practices - WS Authentication / SOA

Tags: web-services, authentication, soa

I am currently developing some webservices for my system, which will be structured around the following SOA model.

But, I need the opinion of other developers, since I'm currently in a standoff:

The system will be totally integrated, just like google services, where we authenticate ourselves on Gmail, for example, and can access all the other services without authenticating again.

So, the problem is, should I implement a dedicated webservice only for authentication(token based), which all other webservices call this one for login, logout and validate user.
Or should I implement the authentication on all services, one by one?

Which is the best practice in this case?